# How to add a Main Menu Scene in Godot?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I am developing a game in Godot 3.5. I have created two levels where player passes through portals. I want to add a start screen which says play and quit. This scene must display before starting level 1 and after end of level 2. How can i add it in this logic?

Here is the logic for level switching:

1. Generatelevel.gd :

```
extends Node2D

# In this array, all levels of the game must be put.
export(Array, PackedScene) var gameLevels = []

var current_level
var level_index = 0

# We start the game with the first level
func _ready():
    next_level()
    
# Prepare the transition to the next level
func transition_to_next_level(old_level):
    $CanvasLayer/AnimationPlayer.play("Transition_in")
    yield($CanvasLayer/AnimationPlayer,"animation_finished")
    old_level.queue_free()  
    current_level = null
# If we are in the last phase, we reset the value. Here it would be to put the end of the game
# But since we don't have it, we start over.
    if level_index == gameLevels.size():
        level_index = 0
    
    yield(get_tree(),"idle_frame")
    next_level()

# Place the next level
func next_level():
    $CanvasLayer/AnimationPlayer.play("Transition_out")
    current_level = gameLevels[level_index].instance()
    level_index += 1
    add_child(current_level)

# Restart the current level
func restart_current_level():
    $CanvasLayer/AnimationPlayer.play("Transition_in")
    yield($CanvasLayer/AnimationPlayer,"animation_finished")
    current_level.queue_free()
    yield(get_tree(),"idle_frame")
    $CanvasLayer/AnimationPlayer.play("Transition_out")
    current_level = gameLevels[level_index - 1].instance()
    add_child(current_level)
```

2. Level.gd code:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    _set_player_camera_limits()

# We define the limits of the player's camera based on the size of the space used by our Tilemap.
func _set_player_camera_limits():
    var map_size = $Tilemaps/GeneralGround.get_used_rect()
    var cell_size = $Tilemaps/GeneralGround.cell_size
    $Player/Camera2D.limit_left = map_size.position.x * cell_size.x 
    $Player/Camera2D.limit_top = map_size.position.y * cell_size.y
    $Player/Camera2D.limit_right = map_size.end.x * cell_size.x
    $Player/Camera2D.limit_bottom = map_size.end.y * cell_size.y

# Sign connected to the closure portal, we move on to the next phase.
func _on_EndLevel_end_current_level():
    if get_parent().has_method("transition_to_next_level"):
        get_parent().transition_to_next_level(self)
    else:
        print("It is not possible to get next level, for this, use GerentiateLevels")
# Signal connected to the boss (if any) to allow the end of the phase.
func _on_WizardBoss_enable_end_level():
    $EndLevel.global_position = Vector2(4303, 439)`
```

I have tried to create a new scene called level 0 and sneak it in with level 1 and 2 because i want to have a main menu after player passes through level 2 portal and starting of game. But i am looking for better solution.

Comment: I see you are handling level instantiation, that is ultimately the most versatile way to go about it. However, I don't know which issue you are facing. With that said, know that you can change the starting scene for your project (either in project settings, or from the context menu in FileSystem), and also you can have autoloads (configure them in project setting, can be scripts or scenes) which will be loaded before the starting scene, and persist even when you change scenes... So they are a convenient place to put logic that you might need to be able to call from anywhere in the scene tree.